# Solving definite Integral involving an absolute parameter

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve this integral:
$$ \int^m_0 \frac{3}{4-x}dx $$
**This is the given solution:**
$$ =3 \int^m_0 \frac{1}{4-x}dx $$
Applying u-substitution,
$ u=4-x $
$$ =3 \int^{4-m}_4 -\frac{1}{u}du $$
$$ =-3\biggl(\Bigl[ln|u|\Bigr]^{4-m}_4\biggr) $$
$$Ans=-3\Bigl(ln(m-4)-2ln(2)\Bigr)$$
I know how to solve definite integrals but for this particular case, could someone explain how the intervals of integration changed from $\int^m_0$ to $\int^{4-m}_4$ and why the u-substitute plugged in the answer is $m-4$ and not $4-m$.

Comment: you also have to change limits according to what you are going to substitute. in this you take $u=4-x$ so when $x=0$ it will $u=4-0=4$ and when $x=m$ it will $u=4-m$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the variable of integration is changed from $x$ to $u$, the values that this variable takes changes.  The relationship between these variables is $u = 4-x$.  So when $x$ is $0$, $u$ takes the value $4-0 = 4$.  When $x$ is $m$, $u$ takes the value $4-m$.  So in the new variable, the bounds of integration are $4$ and $4-m$.

Also, $|4-m| = |(-1)(m-4)| = |-1|\,|m-4| = |m-4|$ so, under the absolute value, the order of subtrahend and minuend is flexible.  When we take $\ln |4-m|$ we take the logarithm of whichever order gives a positive result.  If there is no original (as in, "in the problem statement" or "from the context from which we abstracted this problem") condition on $m$, we should leave the absolute value bars on $|4-m|$.  If there is an original condition on $m$ that at least forces $m > 4$, then the sign of $m-4$ is always positive and that is the order that allows us to write $|m-4| = m-4$ in the logarithm.